# Changing list to string to remove characters

Tags: python, string, list, word-frequency

I have a file that I am trying to do a word frequency list on, but I'm having trouble with the list and string aspects. I changed my file to a string to remove numbers from the file, but that ends up messing up the tokenization. The expected output is a word count of the file I am opening excluding numbers, but what I get is the following:

```
Counter({'<_io.TextIOWrapper': 1, "name='german/test/polarity/negative/neg_word_list.txt'": 1, "mode='r'": 1, "encoding='cp'>": 1})
done
```

Here's the code:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def word_freq(file_tokens):
    global count
    for word in file_tokens:
        count = Counter(file_tokens)
    return count

f = open("german/test/polarity/negative/neg_word_list.txt")

clean = re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', str(f))

file_tokens = clean.split()

print(word_freq(file_tokens))
print("done")
f.close()
```

Comment: Hello, could you add an input and expected result examples?

Comment: `clean = re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', f.read())`?

Comment: *facepalm* i tried everything but f.read which of course worked. thank you!

Comment: Why is `count` global here, and what's the purpose of the `for word in file_tokens:` loop if you are only using `file_tokens` inside the loop, instead of `word`? I think your function can be simplified to just `def word_freq(file_tokens): return Counter(file_tokens)` and then you can simplify it by deleting it and calling `print(Counter(file_tokens))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

this ended up working, thank you to Rakesh

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def word_freq(file_tokens):
    global count
    for word in file_tokens:
        count = Counter(file_tokens)
    return count

f = open("german/test/polarity/negative/neg_word_list.txt")

clean = re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', f.read())

file_tokens = clean.split()

print(word_freq(file_tokens))
print("done")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading further i've noticed you didn't "read" the file, you've just opened it.

if you print only opening the file:

```
f = open("german/test/polarity/negative/neg_word_list.txt")
print(f)
```

You'll notice it will tell you what the object is, "io.TextIOWrapper". So you need to read it:

```
f_path = open("german/test/polarity/negative/neg_word_list.txt")
f = f_path.read()
f_path.close() # don't forget to do this to clear stuff
print(f)
# >>> what's really inside the file
```

or another way to do this without the "close()":

```
# adjust your encoding
with open("german/test/polarity/negative/neg_word_list.txt", encoding="utf-8") as r:
    f = r.read()
```

It's possible that by doing that it won't be in a list, but a plain text file, so you could iterate each line:

```
list_of_lines = []
# adjust your encoding
with open("german/test/polarity/negative/neg_word_list.txt", encoding="utf-8") as r:
    # read each line and append to list
    for line in r:
        list_of_lines.append(line)
```